# Realm Swift Filter Multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm, filtering

Re-asking the question, here, with some modifications to the code:

I have a class called Galaxies, each with a list of Planets

```
class Galaxy: Object {
  let planets = List<Planet>()
}

class Planet: Object {
  dynamic var capitol = String()
  dynamic var council = String()
  dynamic var collective = String()
  dynamic var signals = String()
}
```

I have 10 viewcontrollers, each representing a galaxy with various planets particular to that galaxy. How can I filter for particular planets for a particular galaxy?

When I instantiate a `Results<Galaxy>!` instance with an implicitly unwrapped optional, it compiles in the first Galaxy VC because I have starter data in my AppDelegate. When I do this `let galaxy = Results<Galaxy>? = nil` in the second Galaxy VC, the collection view goes blank.

This makes sense, because there is no data.

So, I guess I have two questions: how do I instantiate a `Results` object and filter for each view controller with no initial data?

I tried `galaxies = realm.objects(Galaxy.self).filter("planets == %@", firstPlanet).sorted(byKeyPath: "capitol", ascending: false)`in `viewDidLoad()` but this crashes:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Finally, `var galaxy = Results<Galaxy>()` raises an exception `cannot invoke initializer for type Results with no arguments`.

Comment: Re-asking _what_ question? If you've already posted a question to Stack Overflow, it's preferable to make edits to that one if needed rather than create a whole other post. Or if referencing a different but related post, linking to it would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For Your View Controller A pass the planets from the selected Galaxy, prepare for segue method

```
var galaxies:[Galaxy] = realm.objects(Galaxy.self)
var selectedGalaxyIndex = 0
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segue_for_ViewController_B") {
        // pass data to next view
        let vc = segue.destination as viewControllerB
        vc.planets = galaxies[selectedGalaxyIndex].planets
    }
}
```

In Your View Controller B add

```
var planets:[Planet]?
```

Answer (score -1):

If there's no initial data, a Realm query will be empty, which appears to be what you want. For example:

```
class Galaxy: Object {
  let planets = List<Planet>()
}

class Planet: Object {
  dynamic var capitol = String()
  dynamic var council = String()
  dynamic var collective = String()
  dynamic var signals = String()
}

let realm = try! Realm()

let galaxies = realm.objects(Galaxy.self)
print(galaxies.count) // => 0
```

As for the `NSException` you're seeing, I suggest you read the whole message printed to the console or logs, as that should instruct you as to what you're doing wrong. From your code fragment, that might be that `firstPlanet` is nil, meaning that `planets == nil` is an illegal query, since a `List` property can never be nil.